# Pre-loading / AJAX - best methods?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I am building a portfolio page, which contains quite anumber of images. I am pulling the image url's from a database, and creating thumbnails from the original source, and the dispaying the thumbnails. When clicked on, displaying the original full size pic.

Loading times are obviuosly affected and the site take some time before displaying anything...

I have tried putting all this in Ajax, but it seems ajax is only reqally effective if the site has initially loaded. As it is now, the site "hangs" while it waits for the on form laod work to be done.

Any ideas on putting a "please wait while iamges laod" section into the container where the iamges will eb displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: squigly fast fingers! and pushed in before having to leave the office... now that that's settled... help!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you create an HTTP handler that your page sends the image IDs to, something like

```
<img src="image-handler.ashx?id=SOME_ID" alt="..." />
```

The key to performance here is that you can then cache the images from this handler. You can save the generated thumbnails to disk and check for existence, and if then use something like `Response.TransferFile()` to send the file (or actually create the thumbnail files on creation of images, not loading them), or even better, apply output caching on the handler, with vary by param to the `id` key.

For the full images also you can use the same techniques. You can also in addition have some hidden images you keep setting their URLs by AJAX before clicking thumbnails, so, they are ready when a thumbnail is clicked and a full image needs to be displayed.

Those are just high level thoughts as per the amount of detail I get from the question.